# Line segment of a ratio distance using only compass and straight edge

Tags: geometry

I need ot draw a line segment of length 1/b given line segment of unit distance 1 and distance b. Using similar triangles I was able to draw out that 1/b = x/a (see below for my work) but I'm unsure on how to go forward from here to actually draw the line segment?[image: similar triangles]

***edit***

Instead of using an arbitrary distance of a for my inner triangle I just used the unit length (1) for both inner and outer triangles to get such:

[image: similar triangles with unit length]

This way 1/b is equal to x/1 or simplified 1/b is equal to line segment x which is already drawn. Is my logic in this correct?

Comment: Yes.  If xQ = b.  xR = 1.  xT = 1 xS = ?? then if RS is parallel to QT then xS = 1b as xQ/xR = xT/xS = QT/RS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close.  You can do this by constructing a line through that point that is parallel to the line between the endpoints.

i.e.

Assuming b > 1.  Draw two  lines intersecting at point x.  Mark off a point B on one  line so that xB = b.  Mark off a point O on the other line that xO = 1. Construct line OB.

Mark of a point 1 on the line xB so that x1 = 1.  Then construct the line, through 1, that is parallel to OB.  That line will intersect xO at point y.

xB/x1 = x0/xy or b/1 = 1/xy so xy = 1/b.